# Sharepoint doesn't display search results

Tags: search, search-results

I have a query rule limiting searches to a particular URL. When I do a search in the query builder on the results.axpx page, when I'm editing the search results web part, I see 171 results. When I do a test search for "development", I see 4 results.

When I go back to http://url/search, and do a test search for "development", I get a message saying that "Nothing here matches your search". HOWEVER, at the bottom of the page, I see a message saying '4 results'. It seems like a display issue, but I haven't changed any of the default Sharepoint result display settings.

[image: display result]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and readded the search results webpart, and everything is the way it's supposed to be. As far as I could tell, I hadn't changed anything with that webpart.